# if statement is not working properly

Tags: linux

I have one file listed as below, which i am reading as input in while loop:

The command `cat status_1.txt` yields:

```
SQLLOADER|FALSE
TX3|TRUE
```

---

Below is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
cat /iris/shrikant/scripts/status_1.txt;
echo
echo
IFS="|"
while read a b
do
date;
c=TRUE
        if [ "${b}" = "${c}" ]; then
        echo $a is freezed;

        else

        echo $a is not freezed;

        fi;

done < status_1.txt;
```

---

but I am not getting the desired output:

```
cat /iris/shrikant/scripts/status_1.txt
SQLLOADER|FALSE
TX3|TRUE

+ cat /iris/shrikant/scripts/status_1.txt
SQLLOADER|FALSE
TX3|TRUE
+ echo

+ echo

+ IFS='|'
+ read a b
+ date
Tue Nov  6 23:38:19 +08 2018
+ c=TRUE
+ '[' $'FALSE\r' = TRUE ']'
+ echo SQLLOADER is not freezed
SQLLOADER is not freezed
+ read a b
+ date
Tue Nov  6 23:38:19 +08 2018
+ c=TRUE
+ '[' $'TRUE\r' = TRUE ']'
+ echo TX3 is not freezed
TX3 is not freezed
+ read a b
```

When value is matching if statement is printing else statement instead of matched conditions.

Comment: Your variable `$b` has a linefeed character in it so it's not going to match a string without linefeed. You'll need to edit `status_1.txt` and remove the control character.

Answer (score 2):

The file `status_1.txt` is a DOS text file.  This is evident from the `\r` (carriage return) at the end of the value of `$b` in the trace output.

You have two options:

1. Convert the text file to Unix text file format through e.g. the `dos2unix` tool, or
2. Take the `\r` into account for `$b` (it will not be present for `$a` as its value is not taken from the end of the line) and test with

   ```
   if [ "$b" = "$c"$'\r' ]
   ```

Comment: if [ "$b" = "$c"$'\r' ] --this option is working now. thank you.

Comment: Again My question for above is status_1.txt file is created in Unix server. There is no way DOS file is generated

Comment: @ShrikantGoud Some web services may output an extra carriage return at the end of each line too. You never mentioned how you create the file, but it is a DOS formatted text file.

Comment: we use an application which have configuration status stored in that file which is present on linux server. i am creating that file via cat file|grep FREEZE > status_1.txt

Comment: SQLLOADER|FALSE|FREEZE
TX3|TRUE||FREEZE
i ignore FREEZE Column by awk again

Answer (score 1):

Your ipout file is in `DOS` format and includes `Carriage Return` characters before the `Newline` characters.

Make sure that your file is in the apropriate UNIX format.

Comment: Again My question for above is status_1.txt file is created in Linux server. There is no way DOS file is generated

Comment: Some UNIX tools (like e.g. `script`) create files with DOS line ends. It is hard to comment your statement unless you explain how you created the file in question.

Comment: we use an application which have configuration status stored in that file which is present on linux server. i am creating that file via cat file|grep FREEZE > status_1.txt

Comment: SQLLOADER|FALSE|FREEZE
TX3|TRUE||FREEZE
i ignore FREEZE Column by awk again

Comment: You should try to find where the cariage Return characters first appear and remove them e.g. via `tr -d '\015'`